# Asymptotic Notation Manipulation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

Say I have a double-indexed sequence $a(n,m)$, with $$∀ n, \quad a(n,m) = f(n) + o(g(m))$$
as $m→∞$ for some sequences $f,g$.
Can I ever then conclude that 
$$a(n,n) \overset{?}{=} f(n) + o(g(n))$$
or for that matter, $a(n,h(n)) \overset{?}{=} f(n) + o(g(h(n)))$

Also, I suspect this is a no, but does anything change if I replace the sequences with functions on $ℝ$ and consider the continuous asymptotics?

Comment: It depends.  Does the $o(g(m))$ term depend on $n$ at all?

Comment: Lets say no? I meant no in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the expression

$$
a(n,m) = f(n) + o(g(m)) \qquad (m \to \infty)
$$

means that there exists some function $b$ such that

$$
a(n,m) = f(n) + b(m)
$$

and $b(x) = o(g(x))$ as $x \to \infty$.  (It is specified in the comments that $b$ depends only on $m$.)  So

$$
a(n,n) = f(n) + b(n),
$$

and $b(n) = o(g(n))$ as $n \to \infty$, thus

$$
a(n,n) = f(n) + o(g(n)) \qquad (n \to \infty).
$$

If $h(n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ then

$$
a(n,h(n)) = f(n) + b(h(n)) = f(n) + o(g(h(n))) \qquad (n \to \infty)
$$

as well.

None of this changes if $n$ and $m$ are considered as continuous variables rather than just integers.

Comment: Thanks, is the situation much more complicated if $f$ depends on $m$ as well? or if $g$ depends on $n$ as well?

Comment: If *the term hidden under the symbol* $o(g(m))$ depends on $n$ (i.e. if $b$ depends on $n$) then the result isn't true in general. Take $b(n,m) = n^2/(n+m)$ and $g(m) = 1$, so that for each fixed $n$ we have $b(n,m) = o(g(m))$ as $m \to \infty$. But, $b(n,n) \neq o(g(n))$ as $n \to \infty$. In order for the statement to still hold we must have $b(n,m) = o(g(m))$ as $m \to \infty$ **uniformly** with respect to $n$.

Comment: And there isn't a problem if $f=f(n,m)$, right?

Comment: Right, $f$ has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! On inspection of my work, there is a sneaky $n$ hiding in $g$, which solves my problem :)